# Lambda function apply on dataframe DOES not contain str

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to add a condition `.apply` with a lambda function that pickups up a keyword but ignores values if they contain a specific word "total."

My dataframe:

```
Section Budget      Hours   Budget  Hours       Total Budget
1       70460.04    702.08  0       0           81581.02
2       137149.03   1141.3  0       0           159823.28
3       33958.35    227.05  0       0           55243.23
4       160688.52   1062    0       0           176156.52
5       1340843.5   12311.650       0           1367133.42
6       73295.25    480     0       0           73295.25
7       0           0       0       0           0
8       1131911.04  6537.96 0       0           1131911.04
9       2216733.4   16425.640       0           3708886.3
```

Here's my code:

```
keyword = budget
row, col = np.where((headers_df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(keyword, case=False)))\
                    & (~headers_df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('total', case=False))))
```

current `col` output:

```
col = (1, 3, 5)
```

Desired `col` output:

```
col = (1, 3)
```

## Question

What am I doing wrong? I have tried the `~` to make it a `NOT` but it's still picking up rows and columns even if they contain the keyword "total."

Comment: Can you post a minimal example to reproduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex like this:

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('(?=.*Budget)^(?!Total)', regex=True)]
```

Output:

```
Index(['Section Budget', 'Budget'], dtype='object')
```

OR

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('budget', case=False) & 
           ~df.columns.str.contains('total', case=False)]
```

Output:

```
Index(['Section Budget', 'Budget'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: thank you for your help. for the regex, is there a way to pass a variable in placed of `budget`?

Comment: Yes using f-string formatting.

Comment: `keyword='budget'`  `df.columns.str.contains(f'{keyword}', case=False)`

Comment: does this look right to you? `row, col = np.where((headers_df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(f'(?=.*{keyword})^(?!Total)', regex=True))))`

Comment: I'm trying to use the lambda because I want to loop through more than just the headers

Comment: my real keyword is: `keyword = 'number of subjects'`